Connection Issue In Bluestacks 5
I use Bluestacks 5 for playing Free Fire.. recently I have had an issue. when I try to play using wifi or ethernet, the match doesn't start. using VPN solves this problem but has a huge ping issue. but when I use a PPPoE connection, there is no issue at all.. ping is so much better.
how to solve the issue for ethernet or wifi?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
